# Is it true that every injective function must be surjective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I believe it is false, because an injective function never maps elements of the domain to the same element of its codomain, where as the surjective function can map an element of the codomain to any element in the domain.

I have some other explanations but they make little sense and are very messy, like this, can someone write a better explanation, or correct me entirely if I am wrong?

Comment: The injective function will be surjective to its image. You can create an example using finite number of objects in both the domain and codomain, with the cardinality(size) of the codomain larger than the domain. If the function is injective and also surjective, both the domain and codomain will be of the same cardinality.

Comment: Do you know what the definitions of injective and surjective are?

Comment: What about $f(x) = e^x$?

Comment: @alexqwx Not quite; the other question is for $f:M\to M$; here the domain and codomain are not necessarily the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My informal way to remember the definitions of injectivity, surjectivity, and bijectivity:

**Injective**:  Every element of the codomain has **at most** one preimage.

**Surjective**:  Every element of the codomain has **at least** one preimage.

**Bijective**:  Every element of the codomain has **exactly** one preimage.

More precisely, if $f : A \to B$ is a mapping of set $A$ to set $B$, then $f$ is

Injective if for every $b \in B$, there is at most one (and possibly no) $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Surjective if for every $b \in B$, there is at least one $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Bijective if for every $b \in B$, there is exactly one $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Under these definitions, clearly, injectivity and surjectivity are not the same concept:  an injective mapping does not require every element in its codomain to have a preimage.  Can we take any injection and *make* it a surjection by modifying the codomain to be the image of $A$ under $f$?  That is to say, is $f : A \to f(A)$ trivially surjective?  Sure, but then the mapping is no longer between the same sets.  This illustrates an important concept of mappings that is frequently overlooked by students new to the concept; namely, that a mapping is characterized by three components:  two sets, and a "rule" or association between them.  The rule is frequently taken to be the focus of attention when working with mappings, but the sets under consideration are also important.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a subset of $B$ and prescribe the function $f:A\rightarrow B$ by $a\mapsto a$.

Then $f$ is evidently injective. However, if $A$ is a **proper** subset of $B$ then the function is not surjective. For elements $b\in B-A\neq\emptyset$ there is no $a\in A$ with $b=f(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(n)=2\cdot n$ is injective from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, but not surjective.